# Assigning an excel cell value to a function

Tags: vba, function, range

I want to assign the value of a cell in a specific worksheet to the function, but the function is returning a zero. Below is my simple code:

```
Function TLGV(Modele As String, Pressure As Integer) 'Total Load Grand Vitesse

    If Modele = "DCHC05" Then
        If Pressure = 30 Then
            Worksheets("VC Types").Activate
            TLGV = Range("H4").Value
        End If
    Else

    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to `Activate` a worksheet from a VBA User Defined function.

```
Function TLGV(Modele As String, Pressure As Integer)

   'Total Load Grand Vitesse

   If Modele = "DCHC05" Then
       If Pressure = 30 Then
           TLGV = Worksheets("VC Types").Range("H4").Value
       End If
    Else
        'more stuff
    End If

End Function
```

In fact, you should provide a parent workbook reference as well.

```
Function TLGV(Modele As String, Pressure As Integer)

   'Total Load Grand Vitesse
   'reference the parent workbook
   with application.caller.parent.parent
     If Modele = "DCHC05" Then
       If Pressure = 30 Then
           TLGV = .Worksheets("VC Types").Range("H4").Value
       End If
      Else
        'more stuff
      End If
    End With

End Function
```